# Launch Outlook from Blackberry Dynamics app

Tags: blackberry, intune, microsoft-graph-intune, blackberry-dynamics

Is it possible to launch outlook from Blackberry dynamics app. If yes, what are the steps to be taken? Is it possible to select the mail client like work or outlook from a blackberry dynamics app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is be possible. Within your app you could launch Microsoft Outlook the same way you would from a non BlackBerry Dynamics app. There are no BlackBerry specific APIs required for that. If you wish to use standard mailto links and open Outlook from BlackBerry Access (the BlackBerry Dynamics browser) the mailto scheme needs to be whitelisted for 3rd party apps by the BlackBerry UEM admin within the BlackBerry Access App Configuration. This method would not use BlackBerry Dynamics Shared Services, but instead uses the native sharing functionality of the device.

To launch a BlackBerry Dynamics app such as BlackBerry Work from another BlackBerry Dynamics app, use the [BlackBerry Dynamics Shared Services Framework](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-android/10_1/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-android-devguide/What-is-the-BlackBerry-Dynamics-SDK/xwk1489609883176/msy1489610500607) with the [Send Email Service](https://marketplace.blackberry.com/services/855115).

BlackBerry Work can also be launched using schemes such as mailto:, gmmmailto: and gwmailto:. This capability can be enabled or disabled by the BlackBerry UEM admin within the BlackBerry Work App Configuration.